# How do I set properties for items in an `ItemGroup` based on the name of the item being added?

Tags: msbuild

Say I have the following `ItemGroup` in my msbuild file:

```
<ItemGroup>
  <!-- build all the .proto files -->
  <MyGroup Include="**/*.txt" MyProperty="[something here to extract metadata for each item]" />
</ItemGroup>
```

What can I put in the brackets to set the property as the itemgroup is filled? Specifically, I would like to get the project-relative path for the file (without the filename). Is something like this possible?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [well-known item metadata](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/msbuild-well-known-item-metadata) inside the item.

```
<Project>
  <ItemGroup>
     <TextFiles Include="**/*.txt"
         MyProperty="Included file %(Filename)(Extension: %(Extension)) in directory %(RelativeDir)" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <Target Name="ListTextFiles">
    <Message Importance="high" Text="@(TextFiles->'%(Identity): %(MyProperty)', '%0A')" />
  </Target>
</Project>
```

with a file structure of

```
fileA.txt
SomeSubfolder\fileB.txt
SomeSubfolder\fileC.txt
```

prints:

```
>dotnet msbuild -t:ListTextFiles -nologo
  fileA.txt: Included file fileA(Extension: .txt) in directory
  SomeSubfolder\fileB.txt: Included file fileB(Extension: .txt) in directory SomeSubfolder\
  SomeSubfolder\fileC.txt: Included file fileC(Extension: .txt) in directory SomeSubfolder\
```